# Building boost on windows with clang 3.6 (no MingW, VS2012 only)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, clang

Is it possible? followed the link here http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2013/10/27057.php and still it cannot handle exception code, which is not yet supported by clang. I've added /GR- /D _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 to the command line in clang-win.jam but it still does not compile with the same ".\boost/throw_exception.hpp(69,5) :  error: cannot compile this throw expression yet"

EDIT001: As of clang3.8 exception are supported, I'll give it another shot
https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21450